# How to make TableView with status = 1 so data stored on jtable

Tags: java, jtable

How to make TableView with query `select * from tableXXX where status='1'`
if status = 1 data shown in jtable
else if status = 0 data not shown in jtable

or how to refresh jtable after status updated from 1 to 0`

Comment: Where the status will be?IS it a part of table content?How will you execute a query?On button click?IF that's the case you can easily do that.Read about TableModel  and DefaultTableModel

Comment: Where is the code?For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 0):

This mycode

```
public class ViewDapur extends JInternalFrame implements ListenerDapur, ListSelectionListener{


private static final long serialVersionUID = -1108049190501656840L;
Connection konek;
Statement state;


//private ControllerDapur controllermak,controllermin;
private ModelDapur modelmak,modelmin;
private TableModelDapur tableModelmak, tableModelmin;



private JTable table;

private JTable tablemak;
private JTable tablemin;


public JTable getInputTable(){
    return table;
}

public ViewDapur() {


    setSize(1320, 590);
    setTitle("DATA ORDERAN TRIPLE SIX");
    setMaximizable(false);
    setIconifiable(true);
    setClosable(true);
    setResizable(true);

    setFrameIcon(new ImageIcon(ViewDapur.class.getResource("/com/sun/javafx/scene/web/skin/Undo_16x16_JFX.png")));
    setBorder(new MatteBorder(2, 2, 2, 2, (Color) Color.MAGENTA));
    setNormalBounds(new Rectangle(20, 0, 0, 0));

    //controllermak = new ControllerPramusaji();
    tableModelmak = new TableModelDapur();
    modelmak = new ModelDapur();
    modelmak.setListener(this);
    //controllermak.setModel(modelmak);

    //controllermin = new ControllerPramusaji();
    tableModelmin = new TableModelDapur();
    modelmin = new ModelDapur();
    modelmin.setListener(this);
    //controllermin.setModel(modelmin);

    init();

    tablemak.setModel(tableModelmak);
    tablemak.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);

    tablemin.setModel(tableModelmin);
    tablemin.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false); 

try {
        loadDatabasemak();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    try {
        loadDatabasemin();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

/*  Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            viewTabelMakanan("1");
            viewTabelMinuman("1");
            }
     });


    timer.start();timer.setRepeats(false);
*/  //refreshTablemamin();
    //viewTabelMakanan("1");
    //viewTabelMinuman("1");

}



/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                //Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                //    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        ViewDapur frame = new ViewDapur();
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                //      }
                // });


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
private void init(){


    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(new Color(119, 136, 153));
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(), "......"));
    getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);


    tablemak = new JTable();

    tablemak.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
        new Object[][] {
        },
        new String[] {
            "No Meja", "Menu", "Jumlah", "No Antri"
        }
    ));

    JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
    panel_2.setBounds(10, 11, 640, 540);

    panel_2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
            BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(), "Daftar Order Makanan"));
    panel_2.setLayout(null);
    panel_2.add(tablemak);
    panel.add(panel_2);

    JScrollPane scrollPane2 = new JScrollPane(tablemak,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane2.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane2.setBounds(10, 26, 616, 502);
    panel_2.add(scrollPane2);

    scrollPane2.setViewportView(tablemak);

    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    panel_1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(

    BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(), "Daftar Order Minuman"));
    panel_1.setBounds(660, 11, 650, 537);
    panel.add(panel_1);
    panel_1.setLayout(null);

    tablemin = new JTable();
    tablemin.setBounds(241, 24, 0, 0);
    panel_1.add(tablemin);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tablemin,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.setBounds(10, 25, 627, 501);
    panel_1.add(scrollPane);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(tablemin);





}





private void loadDatabasemak() throws ErrorInfo, SQLException{
    DAOdapur daovi = UtilGlobal.getDAOdapur();
    tableModelmak.setList(daovi.selectAll());

}
private void loadDatabasemin() throws ErrorInfo, SQLException{
    DAOdapur daovi = UtilGlobal.getDAOdapur();
    tableModelmin.setList(daovi.selectAll2());


}


@Override
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
}

@Override
public void onDelete() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
public void onChange(ModelDapur model) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
public void refreshTablemamin() {
    tablemak.revalidate();
    tablemak.repaint();
    tablemak.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
    tablemin.revalidate();
    tablemin.repaint();
    tablemin.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
    tableModelmak.fireTableDataChanged();
    tableModelmin.fireTableDataChanged();
}

public void viewTabelMakanan(String status){
    //mejahe="";
    try {
        konek = Koneksi.getKoneksi();
        state = konek.createStatement();

        String query = "select * from tbtrans where katmenu='MAKANAN' AND stord='"+status+"' AND stdpr='0'";
        ResultSet result= state.executeQuery(query);

         while(result.next()){

            Dapur p = new Dapur();

            p.setNokey(result.getString("nokey"));
            p.setNovisitor(result.getString("novisitor"));
            p.setNomeja(result.getInt("nomeja"));
            p.setNoantri(result.getInt("noantri"));
            p.setAddedpeg(result.getString("addedpeg"));
            p.setKdmc(result.getInt("kdmc"));
            p.setMncafe(result.getString("mncafe"));
            p.setKatmenu(result.getString("katmenu"));

            p.setQty(result.getDouble("qty"));
            p.setHrg(result.getDouble("hrg"));
            p.setSubtotal(result.getDouble("subtotal"));
            p.setWorder(result.getString("worder"));
            p.setStord(result.getInt("stord"));
            p.setWsaji(result.getString("wsaji"));
            p.setStdpr(result.getInt("stdpr"));
            p.setStkasir(result.getInt("stkasir"));
            p.setPegkasir(result.getString("pegkasir")); 

        tableModelmak.add(p);
        tableModelmak.fireTableDataChanged();
          }     
     }
     catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();

     } 
    //Pramusaji p = new Pramusaji();

}
public void viewTabelMinuman(String status){
    //mejahe="";
    try {
        konek = Koneksi.getKoneksi();
        state = konek.createStatement();

        String query = "select * from tbtrans where katmenu='MINUMAN' AND stord='"+status+"' AND stdpr='0'";
        ResultSet result= state.executeQuery(query);

         while(result.next()){

            Dapur p = new Dapur();

            p.setNokey(result.getString("nokey"));
            p.setNovisitor(result.getString("novisitor"));
            p.setNomeja(result.getInt("nomeja"));
            p.setNoantri(result.getInt("noantri"));
            p.setAddedpeg(result.getString("addedpeg"));
            p.setKdmc(result.getInt("kdmc"));
            p.setMncafe(result.getString("mncafe"));
            p.setKatmenu(result.getString("katmenu"));

            p.setQty(result.getDouble("qty"));
            p.setHrg(result.getDouble("hrg"));
            p.setSubtotal(result.getDouble("subtotal"));
            p.setWorder(result.getString("worder"));
            p.setStord(result.getInt("stord"));
            p.setWsaji(result.getString("wsaji"));
        p.setStdpr(result.getInt("stdpr"));
        p.setStkasir(result.getInt("stkasir"));
        p.setPegkasir(result.getString("pegkasir")); 

        tableModelmin.add(p);
        tableModelmin.fireTableDataChanged();
          }     
     }
     catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
} 
//Pramusaji p = new Pramusaji();
}



}
```

Comment: data just shown in Jtable where condition status = 1